# how to get page title of google seargh page (page source and inspect element are not same)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i need to get page title of google search page.
for example when i type "apple" in google
then i get url which is "https://www.google.co.kr/search?q=apple&oq=apple&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1409j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8".
and what i want to get is "apple-google search" which is tab's title.
i already tried using ajax, but what i got was "google" which was title of page source,
as inspect element and page source were different. 
simply i want to get tab title which is title in inspect element not in page source.
how can i get it??

Answer (score 0):

The page title is contained in the tag and this value is global to the document element.

```
<title>apple-google search</title>
```

So, to get this value you can:

```
document.title
```

Comment: thx.i'm making chrome extension and i have list of some urls which is needed to get titltes. i already tried using document.title, but i failed.